# A change on the state does not recompose the view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following issue where the state change on the counter variable does not trigger recomposition of the Text component. Any ideas of what might be the problem???

```
@Model
class CounterState(var counter:Int = 0)

@Composable
fun CounterView(counterState: CounterState){
     Column {
         Text(text= "${counterState.counter}", 
              style=(+typography()).body1)

         Button(text ="Increment", 
                onClick = {counterState.counter++},
                style = ContainedButtonStyle())
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        app {
            CounterView(CounterState())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but on every click text is changing for me.

Comment: Are you testing that in an emulator or real device? the preview of android studio doesn't respond to clicks at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

`var counter by +state { 0 }
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "$counter",
            style = (+typography()).body1
        )
        Button(
            text = "Increment",
            onClick = { counter++ },
            style = ContainedButtonStyle()
        )
    }`